# Fixing an Android app (no crash) without access to the device (another country, thousands of users etc)

Tags: android, debugging, logging

How do I debug a customer's install of an app? There could be ten thousand customers, and some may be in other countries, and getting access to the phone is not possible. I don't mean crashes, I mean unexpected behaviour, such as the registration and login not working as expected, but with no way of knowing when it's happened. For example, the user enters their credentials and it thinks the user is not registered because of something wrong in the database... everything will appear as normal in the app, but it's not what's supposed to happen, so ACRA won't help.

Is there some way of logging everything that's going on in the app and sending it to the developer? And a way of turning it on and off for a specific device?

Comment: you can always direct your log to your own end. putting in a correct URL to monitor everything on the application function. check [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-remote-stacktrace/)  for more understanding.

Comment: Agree with @IsraelMeshileya, Logs would be the way to go. For example in my app i use Fabric.io and then when unexpected behevior happens i log it as a non-fatal exception with all the info i need to debug it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you immediately employ a Crashlytics tool. It will not only help you in cases like above but, also give key usage insight. For the cases you mentioned above, you can employ failure states as 'events' (For e.g. a failure to log-in, etc.). These events can then be seen on your tool dashboard and you can get a pretty good picture. Like mentioned above already, depending on your use case it'd be better to log these behavior for a more clearer picture.

A basic Crashlytic tool implementation is generally very easy and quick. Most of the tools like Crashlytics by Fabric, Google Analytics, etc are even free.

Comment: I installed it and it only logs if there's a crash which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Well, Crashlytics by Fabric primarily does that. There are other suits in Fabric too. Or, you can look into Google Analytics.

Comment: @Questioner thats what i said in my comment above and reiterate, its primarily designed for that only. There are other suits in Fabric too, you can look at them. Or, you can look into Google Analytics